# How to call a method which reads data from a file?

Tags: java, facebook

The question is

> Write a method `readStock(String[] sAr, double[] pAr, int[] qAr)` to read the following details from a file named “stock.txt”.

So I created the stock file which contain

```
pillow    14.50    30
Sheet     43       40
Quilt     52.50    40
Set       100      200
```

and I do this method

```
public static void readStock(String[] sAr, double[] pAr, int[] qAr) throws FileNotFoundException 
 {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("stock.txt")) ;
 int i = 0;
 while (input.hasNext())
 {
    sAr[i]= input.next();
    pAr[i] = input.nextDouble();
    qAr[i] =input.nextInt();
    i++;

         }
 input.close();
     System.out.print("ITEM"+"          "+"Price"+"          "+"Quantity");
 for (i=0;i<qAr.length;i++)
 {
     System.out.println(sAr[i]+"          "+pAr[i]+"          "+qAr[i]+"");
 }
 }
```

but I don't know the way to call it ?

I did

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

         readStock();

    }
}
```

but there is an error.

Comment: Take all your parameters out of the method signature and declare them inside your method.  You'll either need to know in advance how big to make the arrays or use ArrayLists instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass in 3 corresponding parameters, in your case they are `String[] sAr, double[] pAr, int[] qAr`. Therefore you should do something like `readStock(sAr, pAr, qAr);`

Answer (score 0):

You require 3 parameters in you method signature, 3 arrays so you need to pass them to the method. You can do it like: `readStock(new String[4], new double[4], new int[4]);` However with this design you need to know how many lines you file contains (because you need to create arrays with proper size). To make it work with any file length just replace arrays with Lists:

> ```
> public static void readStock(List<String> names, List<Double> prices, List<Integer> quantity) throws FileNotFoundException
> {
>
>     Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("stock.txt")) ;
>     while (input.hasNext())
>     {
>         names.add(input.next());
>         prices.add(input.nextDouble());
>         quantity.add(input.nextInt());
>     }
>     input.close();
>     System.out.print("ITEM"+"          "+"Price"+"          "+"Quantity");
>     for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++)
>     {
>         System.out.println(names.get(i)+"          "+prices.get(i)+"          "+quantity.get(i)+"");
>     }
> }
> ```

Lists have the ability to expand their size when you are adding an element and there is not enough space for him. To create new List you can use for example `new ArrayList<String>()`